# How many racks should I set in my ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES cluster has 20 machines with 50 nodes(ES instances), I'm not sure how many racks should I set. Is two racks enough? or 3 or 4 racks better.

As I know if I set rack_id in ES configuration, it can provide the following functions:

```
1, Select data location or relocation(to make sure replicas in different racks)
2, Use Rack_id as doc routing
```

Any reasons should I set more racks, but I think even just one rack by default is good too.

Comment: Virtual Machines or multiple nodes on the same OS?

Comment: each physical machine has two ES nodes with same OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance of an outage of two machines is highest if they share hardware because you use VMs, smaller if they share a rack but not hardware, and again smaller if they share a building but not a rack. So it makes sense to use more than a single rack.

Whether you need more than 2 racks depends on your replicas. The default number of replications is 1. If you require a higher value, strictly speaking you will degrade the Availability of your cluster a bit if you use only 2 racks because the >= 3 setting will not be effective on the rack level.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand the relation between replication number and rack number, but I can not understand why the rack number would affect the availability of the cluster? Could you please give explanation about the availability.

Comment: If your application requires a very high level of Availability, you could introduce a requirement _system should remain Available with 2 failbacks gone_. So you put `replication` to `2`, meaning 3 copies of every Shard exist (Primary, Replicate, Replicate). If you spread this over 2 racks, you will invariably end up with either `[(P,R),(R)]` or `[(P),(R,R)]`, ES will never do `[(P,R,R),()]`, if you catch my notation. Your requirement will be satisfied for _nodes_, but not if two _racks_ fail at the same time. I also recommend to look at what Andrei suggests.

Comment: Thanks Loek, I've sent the 50 bonus to you :) Just a quick question please, If my ES cluster has 100 servers, normally how many replicates should I set better? And, the rack number should be always greater than replicates number, right please?

Comment: Yes, I believe amount of racks should be the same or greater than the amount of copies. Greater only if so by other considerations, not because of any improvements in Availability or Performance, but maybe because the hardware doesn't fit, etc. So if `replicas=2`, total copies is `2+1`, and racks should be `>= 2+1`. How many replicas you should set is up to your Availability requirements, it's about certainty and uptime. `replicas=1` should be fine for most cases. Happy to discuss your specifics offline.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, it's simpler and easier to just set `cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host` to `true`. (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html) This will prevent copies of the same shard to be placed on the same host (host is identified by address and host name). Please, test this before going in production with this approach.

Also, keep in mind that you need to specify the `processors` setting (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html#processors) accordingly. Each ES node detects the # of cores available on the machine (not aware of other nodes present). With multiple nodes on the same machine, each node can think that it has dedicated access to all cores on the machine (this can be problematic for the default thread pool sizes are derived from this).  So you will want to explicitly specify the # of cores available via the `processors` setting so that it does not end up over-allocating the thread pools.

I recommend using dedicated master nodes and to ensure cluster stability, each dedicated master node instance should be on its own machine (certainly can be a much smaller machine, e.g. 4Gb of RAM to start with).